# Setting Dynanic Path for XLookup with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, xlookup

I am trying to make a dynamic Macro that takes the path in cells that users enter and paste them into other cells but its not working

Here are my variables

```
Dim FRLU As String
Dim LU As String

dir = Range("B1").Value
FRLU = Range("B2").Value
LU = Range("B3").Value
```

Table:

| Enter Working Directory into B1: | C:\Users\User1\Documents\Test1 |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Enter first Workbook into B2: | workbook1.xlsx |  |  |  |
| Enter second Workbook into B3: | workbook2.xlsx |  |  |  |

This is the script I have that enters the XLookup into the new column:

```
lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

Range("N4").Formula = "=XLOOKUP(G4,'dir[FRLU]ColumnG'!$G$2:$G$1000,'dir[FRLU]ColumnE'!$E$2:$E$1000)
Range("N4").Copy Range("N5:N" & lngLastRow)
```

This gets entered into the cell and is copied all the way through the new column and throws me #N/A:

```
=XLOOKUP(G4,'dir[FRLU]ColumnG'!$G$2:$G$1000,'dir[FRLU]ColumnE'!$E$2:$E$1000)
```

This is what I want it to say:

```
=XLOOKUP(G4,'C:\Users\User1\Documents\Test1[workbook1.xlsx]ColumnG'!$G$2:$G$1000,'C:\Users\User1\Documents\Test1[workbook1.xlsx]ColumnE'!$E$2:$E$1000)
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: variables don't belong inside quotes, and need concatenated with `&`.

Comment: Sorry about the table, It looked correct when I was editing the post but it doesn't appear as one when posted

Comment: Don't use `dir` as a variable name, as that shadows the [`Dir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function) function.

Comment: @BigBen I've changed it to cellB1 but now it does:
```
=xlookup(G4,'C:\Users\User1\Documents\Test1\[&FRLU]Finance Reportable Living Un'!$G$2:$G$1000,'C:\Users\User1\Documents\Test1\[&FRLU]Finance Reportable Living Un'!$E$2:$E$1000)
```

Comment: It looks like `FRLU` is still inside quotes.

Comment: @BigBen I'm not sure what quotes you are referring to:

Range("N4").Formula = "=xlookup(G4,'directory\[FRLU]Finance Reportable Living Un'!$G$2:$G$1000,'directory\[FRLU]Finance Reportable Living Un'!$E$2:$E$1000)"

This now causes an endless popup of Update Value:[FRLU]

Comment: `FRLU` falls within the outermost `"` quotes. You need `"=XLOOKUP(G4,'directory[" & FRLU & "]Finance....` and so on, where `FRLU` is no longer inside the quotes, and is concatenated with `&`.